# Error when creating xml from mySQL database with php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps

I am following this tutorial from google for google maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=es

I formatted my code as so:

```
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
for($i = 0; $i< $breweryNum; $i++ ){

    echo '<marker ';
    echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['beerBrewery']) . '" ';
    echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    echo 'lng="' . $row['longi'] . '" ';
    echo '/>';


}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

But when I run the php file to test my xml, I get this:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://beerportfolio.com/getMapMarkers.php
Line Number 1, Column 18:<markers><marker <br />
-----------------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you use nl2br or some to output resulting string?

It's clear error message,  after "`<markers><marker`" outputs tag "`<br />`" but here should be your "name" attribute.
Anyway, you can use following code to not output wrong things:

```
$out = '<markers>';
for($i = 0; $i< $breweryNum; $i++ ){

    $out .= '<marker ';
    $out .= 'name="' . parseToXML($row['beerBrewery']) . '" ';
    $out .= 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    $out .= 'lng="' . $row['longi'] . '" ';
    $out .= '/>';

}
$out .= '</markers>';
```

Comment: Tried your code, and now I get this error:

XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://beerportfolio.com/getMapMarkers.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^

When I use this code:

$out = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';



// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
$out = '<markers>';
for($i = 0; $i< $breweryNum; $i++ ){

    $out .= '<marker ';
    $out .= 'name="' . $row['beerBrewery'] . '" ';
    $out .= 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    $out .= 'lng="' . $row['longi'] . '" ';
    $out .= '/>';

}
$out .= '</markers>';

Comment: You probably forget to     echo $out;

Comment: Also, I think you need provide more code. You iterating by $breweryNum but outputting data from $row

Comment: SO I was an idiot and didt echo the $out but I am still getting more errors:

Here is more code:


$resultBrew = $db->query($query);
$breweryNum = $resultBrew->num_rows;

$out = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';


// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
$out = '<markers>';
for($i = 0; $i< $breweryNum; $i++ ){
 $row = $resultBrew->fetch_assoc();
    $out .= '<marker ';
    $out .= 'name="' .  parseToXML($row['beerBrewery']) . '" ';
    $out .= 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
    $out .= 'lng="' . $row['longi'] . '" ';
    $out .= '/>';

}
$out .= '</markers>';

echo $out;

Comment: The error I am getting with that is:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: Now I see in source of http://beerportfolio.com/getMapMarkers.php error message, what parsetoxml() is not defined. In example what you code is based on (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=es), this function is presented. So, you need copy it into you code too

Answer (score 0):

First up, XML files often begin with their type declaration.  This isn't required but is helpful (i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` )

You seem to have `<br />` being output within your xml.  You may find it simpler to instead do something like

```
$strOutput = '<markers>';
```

And then

```
$strOutput .= '<marker name="' . parseToXML($row['beerBrewery']) . '" lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" lng="' . $row['longi'] . '" />';
```

And closing off with

```
$strOutput = '</markers>';
echo $strOutput;
```